# Localization - "error: read failed: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I´m getting:

> error: read failed: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the
>   correct format.

When trying to run my localized file:

```
"Hi" = "Hi translated"
"Bye" = "Bye translated"
```

Any ideas why? Only found other answers in Objective-C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you´re using Swift which don´t require `;`, you still need to use semicolon in your localized files. Correct format will be:

```
"Hi" = "Hi translated";
"Bye" = "Bye translated";
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `;` at the end of each line

```
"Hi" = "Hi translated";
"Bye" = "Bye translated";
```